# input value change by flash event

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I am using a flash object that puts a value to a textarea element. I need to know the jquery event that would be triggered if the value of a text area is changed by a flash object.

What I need to do is, if the value of the textarea is changed ( by the flash object, no keypress or lost focus ), a certain checkbox would change to 'checked' state.

I have tried `.bind( 'input' )` but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery **`change`** event

```
$('.txtarea').change(function() {

//call your handler   

});
```

you should use jquery ON method to bind the event to element

```
$(".txtarea").on("change", function(event){
    //alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: i tried the change event but it does not trigger when the flash object has changed the value of the textarea